# Elisp nested function stops execution

Tags: buffers, functions

I can not figure out why does when I factored out function it started to work wrong. 
Here's the my function to kill all dired buffers, its bound to `dired-mode-map` that work as expected and successfully kill all dired buffers when I invoke it in dired buffer:

```
(defun sandric/dired-kill-buffers ()
  (interactive)
  (mapc (lambda (buffer)
          (when (eq 'dired-mode (buffer-local-value 'major-mode buffer))
            (kill-buffer buffer)))
        (buffer-list)))
```

I decided to factor out a function to kill all buffers by major mode name:

```
(defun sandric/kill-buffers-by-major-mode (mode-name)
  "Kill open buffers by major mode name"
  (interactive)
  (mapc (lambda (buffer)
          (when (eq mode-name (buffer-local-value 'major-mode buffer))
            (kill-buffer buffer)))
        (buffer-list)))

(defun sandric/dired-kill-buffers ()
  (interactive)
  (sandric/kill-buffers-by-major-mode 'dired-mode))
```

And now it works wrongly - it kills only current dired buffer and not killing parent ones. I can not understand why - it looks like nested function get bounded to current buffer and stops executing after it gets killed. Can anyone explain me why is it so and how to fix it?

Comment: `C-h v mode-name`

Comment: Great example of the pitfalls of dynamic binding!

Answer (score 2):

The variable `mode-name` is a buffer-local variable that is also bound inside your function `sandric/kill-buffers-by-major-mode`.  Under dynamic scoping, that means that the value of `mode-name` seen by your code will change when you change buffers (in this case, when you kill the current buffer).  See the warning [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Intro-to-Buffer_002dLocal.html#Intro-to-Buffer_002dLocal) about `let` bindings; it also applies to function arguments.

This problem goes away for me if the function is defined using lexical scope, but according to [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Lexical-Binding.html#Using-Lexical-Binding), this is undefined behavior and using a special variable such as `mode-name` as a function argument is discouraged.

So the correct solution is just to change the name of your function argument from `mode-name` to another symbol that is not defined as buffer-local.

(Thanks to Tobias for explaining the details of the problematic interaction in the comments; my previous explanation was very sketchy, and I made some unfounded assumptions about what was causing the problem.)

Comment: See the warning of https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Intro-to-Buffer_002dLocal.html#Intro-to-Buffer_002dLocal. `let`-binding is weaker than changing the buffer for buffer-local variables. If you `let`-bind a buffer local variable the value of the variable changes also in the scope of the `let`-binding when changing the buffer.

Comment: -- After changing the buffer the value of the other buffer is `let`-bound and not the value of the current one. (Sorry for splitting the comment. It is because the 5 minute-phase has expired. I had an urgend call in the middle of editing.) Maybe, function arguments are similar to `let`-binding?

Comment: In dynamical binding `mode-name` is bound in the lambda through the surrounding function. The lambda is not used outside the function.

Comment: The output of the following example is `tst=a tst=b`:
`(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*a*")
  (setq-local tst 'a))

(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*b*")
  (setq-local tst 'b))

(defun test-tst (tst)
  (with-current-buffer "*a*"
    (message "tst=%s" tst))
  (with-current-buffer "*b*"
    (message "tst=%s" tst))
  )

(test-tst 'c)`. Meaning one must be careful not only with `let`-bindings but also with function arguments. :-( -- It has nothing to do with actually killing the buffer just with changing the current buffer. On killing the current buffer is changed.

Comment: You can use the package https://github.com/Lindydancer/lisp-extra-font-lock It highlights all bound variables, e.g. parameters and variables bound by `let'. It highlights `defvar':ed variables using a different color, so it's apparent that `mode-name' is a special name.